# keep track of pairs changement

Tags: c, algorithm

Suppose I have a certain number of consecutive numbers to which I assign another number. For example, the following pairs:

```
0 -> 1

1 -> 2

2 -> 0

3 -> 0

4 -> 1

5 -> 3
```

Next, I call a function that adjusts the numbers on the right:

```
0 -> 2

1 -> 0

2 -> 0

3 -> 0

4 -> 2

5 -> 2
```

Now I need to loop over all the possible numbers that are on the right side (0 and 2 in this case) and do something with them. The problem is that after calling the function, I don't know how many different numbers are on the right side, so now I can't determine the number of iterations of my loop and I also don't know which numbers to loop over.
So I don't know which is the most-performant way to keep track of the changes made by the function. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please show your code rather than describing it in words alone. That is, provide a [mre].

Comment: A common data structure for keeping track of a set of things is a hash table.  But my guess is that you're overthinking the problem.

Comment: Try "brute-force" method first. If needed think about optimizing (algorithm, code, ...) **after you have it working and measured**. [Premature optiomization is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)